# Check if blur was triggered by click on div

Tags: jquery, jquery-autocomplete

I have an input and on blur I want to save the value.
The problem is that I have autocomplete on and when the users clicks on a suggestion from the autocomplete list the blur is triggered.

For example: the users enters "iP" in the input and then clicks "iPhone" from the autocomplete list. In this caste both "iP" and "iPhone" values are stored ("iP" store triggered by blur and "iPhone" store triggered by autocomplete click).

I was thinking about checking if the blur action was triggered by a click on the autocomplete list.

```
$('input').blur(function(e){
  if(e.IsClickOnAutocomplete)
     return;
  else save_value;
});
```

So, how can I check in which way the blur was triggered?

**EDIT**
Here, a jsFiddle that shows something simillar to my problem http://jsfiddle.net/mkp8m/1

Comment: Why do you want to save anything on a mere blur event? That's really surprising behavior.

Comment: Because atm the value is saved when the user presses space. If the user enters a value and then moves to another field, or clicks something else on the site the value will not be saved.

Comment: I don't think it's "suprising behavior" at all. Wouldn't you expect that after you write a tag on SO in the Tags input and then blur that field the tag should be saved?

Comment: Well it isn't saved. It is "saved" only after pressing space or clicking one of suggested tags, blurring doesn't do anything. It is really saved when you press save changes.

Comment: I know that on SO blur does nothing, but I feel like doing so is much more intuitive for the user. If he only enters one tag he shouldn't be forced to press "space" for the tag to appear as one. And I am not saving them, I just said "save" to make it the question shorter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, after making clear what `autocomplete` you mean, here is the solution.

Use [`change`](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#event-change) event of autocomplete plugin:

```
change: function(event, ui) {
    // save(this.value);
}
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/mkp8m/2/